# How to select values from two table in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to fetch data from two table simultaneously from mysql database but i cant use join since the query has other parameter that needs to be considered.
here is my query

```
SELECT * 
from `c_detail` 
where `c_id` in  (SELECT `job_c_id` 
                  from `applied_jobs` 
                  where `applied_f_id` IN (SELECT `f_detail_id` 
                                           from `f_detail`
                                           WHERE `f_email` = '{$_SESSION['f_email']}'
                                          )
                 )
```

here i want to select a column of table `applied_jobs`.
Can we do this in the same query above?

Comment: Rewrite your WHERE .. IN to joins.

Comment: can you write it since it throw a error in mine when i am trying it on phpmyadmin

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: So far you are selecting data from `c_detail`. What is the other table you want to select from? Your query involves three tables so far, but we don't know anything about those tables. What are their unique keys? What do they contain? Please show sample data and the expected result. (You can remove all those ugly backticks, by the way. You don't need them, because all your table and column names obey the rules for well-formed names.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
    SELECT * 
    FROM `c_detail`, `c_dtl`
    JOIN `applied_jobs`.`jobs` ON `c_dtl`.`c_id` = `jobs`.`job_c_id`
    JOIN  `f_detail`.`f_dtl` ON `jobs`.`applied_f_id` = `f_dtl`.`f_detail_id`
    WHERE `f_email` = '{$_SESSION['f_email']}'
```

You can use applied_jobs column using alias